# Setting Routes for Deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I´ve created my first React app using Webpack. Now I want to make this app reachable outside of my development Environment, but I don´t get it working.

For development i run on my local computer:

`"start": "node server.js",`

This makes my React app reachable via `localhost:3000`. This works great.

But now I want to deploy my react app on an external server with a domain. 
To create a bundle of my Code I hit

`"build": "webpack -p"`this generates a bundle file in a subfolder `MyProjectFolder/dist/bundle.js`. Afterwards I copied my `index.html` to `/dist/` and included the bundle file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Urlaub-planer</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Auth0Lock script -->
<script src="//cdn.auth0.com/js/lock-9.0.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="todoapp" id="root"></div>
   <!--<script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>-->
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

These both filed where then copied to my external server which runs apache.
The webfolder on the server has the same name than my ProjectFolder.
I then tried to access my App via

`https://myDomain.de/MyProjectFolder/index.html

This show me this error:

[image: Error MSG]

I guess, I have to change my Router setup, but I have currently no clue how to do this. In my development environment, the Project Folder is not included in the URL, when I access my App, could this be part of the problem? Can anyone guide me through this please?
This problem seems to be very basic for some of you, but it is my first time using all these new technologies, and I tried already so much, and still the same error message. What do I have to do, to deploy my React App on an external server, running apache, with a different domain. Please Help me.

This is the File where my Routes are defined (ProjectFolder/index.js)

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'

 import App from './containers/App'
 import VacationSummary from './containers/vacation/VacationSummary'
 import VacationRequest from './containers/vacation/VacationRequest'
 import VacationRequestSummary from './containers/vacation/VacationRequestSummary'

 import Home from './containers/Home'
 import Demo from './components/Demo'
 import rootReducer from './reducers/reducers'
 import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

 var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
 injectTapEventPlugin();

 const logger = createLogger();

  let createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, logger)  (createStore)

  let store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer)

  let rootElement = document.getElementById('root')

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
     module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
    const nextRootReducer = require('./reducers').default
    store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer)
    })
  }

  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
         <Route path="Home" component={Home}/>
         <Route path="VacationSummary" component={VacationSummary}/>
         <Route path="VacationRequest" component={VacationRequest}/>
         <Route path="VacationRequestSummary" component= {VacationRequestSummary}/>
     </Route>
  </Router>
    </Provider>,
    rootElement
  )
```

Finally my package.json

```
   {
   "name": "Urlaubsplaner",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
     "server": "node server/server.js",
      "start": "node server.js",
      "watch": "webpack --watch",
      "production": "webpack -p"
    },
    "author": "Auth0",
     "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
     "classnames": "^2.2.5",
     "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
      "material-ui": "^0.15.2",
     "moment": "^2.13.0",
     "react": "^15.1.0",
     "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.1.0",
     "react-dom": "*",
     "react-redux": "*",
     "react-router": "*",
      "react-tabs": "^0.7.0",
      "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
      "react-yearly-calendar": "^1.1.4",
    "redux": "*",
     "redux-form": "^5.2.5",
     "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
      "redux-thunk": "*",
     "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
    },
   "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.6.18",
    "babel-loader": "^5.1.4",
     "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^1.1.0",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "webpack": "^1.9.11",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.2.0"
    }
  }
```

And my webpack.config

```
  var path = require('path')
 var webpack = require('webpack')

 module.exports = {
   devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
   entry: [
   'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './index'
   ],
   output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
     publicPath: '/static/'
   },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
   ],
   module: {
     loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      {test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: [ 'babel' ],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname
      }]
    }
  }
```

UPDATE:

I have searched for solution and found this github thread :[Github](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/310)
Based on this information I have removed

`history={browserHistory}` from my Router and now I see at least my App, but I get a new error, that is similar to the old one.

[image: New Error]

After Reading the message, I have updated my code

```
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router'
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
     <Route path="/" component={App}>
         <Route path="/Home" component={Home}/>
         <Route path="/VacationSummary" component={VacationSummary}/>
         <Route path="/VacationRequest" component={VacationRequest}/>
         <Route path="/VacationRequestSummary" component={VacationRequestSummary}/>
     </Route>
  </Router>
```

But I´m still getting the error message above. One ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you need different configurations for environments you can create different webpack configuration files and expose global constants with the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin).

If you have already set your environment in your system or container, you'd write something like:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
})
```

This way you can access `process.env.NODE_ENV` in your React code and create different routes at your convenience.

Comment: ah great advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for solution and found this github thread :[Github][2]
Based on this information I have removed

`history={browserHistory}` from my Router and now I see at least my App, but I get a new error, that is similar to the old one.

After Reading the message, I have updated my code

```
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router'
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
     <Route path="/" component={App}>
         <Route path="/Home" component={Home}/>
         <Route path="/VacationSummary" component={VacationSummary}/>
         <Route path="/VacationRequest" component={VacationRequest}/>
         <Route path="/VacationRequestSummary" component={VacationRequestSummary}/>
     </Route>
  </Router>
```

But there was still the error mentioned above  (Updated Q). After I excluded

```
 if (module.hot) {
  // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
  module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
  const nextRootReducer = require('./reducers').default
  store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer)
 })
}
```

The error was gone. Now I still got this error

`EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.`

But I think this has nothing to do with the Problem described in the Question